# Symfony2 - Two or more bundles into into the same folder

Tags: symfony, bundle, scaffolding, symfony-2.3, runtimeexception

It's possible with Symfony2 to have two or more bundles into the same folder?

Below an example of folder structure:

```
src/User/RegBundle
src/User/CityBundle
```

I ask this because i tried this structure, but when i run the entities creation it generates just the entities' RegBundle folder.

In fact, through this command

```
$ php app/console doctrine:generate:entities UserRegBundle
```

the entities' accessories are correctly generated into *src/User/RegBundle*

Instead, through this command

```
$ php app/console doctrine:generate:entities UserCityBundle
```

i get this error

```
 [RuntimeException]                                             
 Bundle "UserCityBundle" does not contain any mapped entities.
```

Then, my dupt is, can i use this folder structure?
If the response is yes, there's a particular way to call the entities generation?

Comment: What is the return of the command `php app/console doctrine:schema:validate` ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you sure can. Just make sure you have entities in the `UserCityBundle`.

Comment: That's sure. I have the folder "Entity" into the `UserCityBundle` where there are my entities correctly structured.
There's a different way to call the entities generation?

Comment: Then doublecheck the namespaces and that you've correctly registered the bundle.

Comment: In my _config.yml_ i've just this line into the orm voice:
`orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        auto_mapping: true`
Should i add the bundle configuration?